# 投票の公平性について

Tags: サポート

（デリケートな話題で恐縮ですが、）
特定の質問者、話題に対し、過敏にマイナスの評価をしているユーザーに対して、
誰かが何らかの処置を行なっているのでしょうか？

それとも、過敏にマイナスの評価をしているという判断自体が主観的なものであり、
中立を守る（何もしない）のが正しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

少なくとも同一ユーザーによる短時間の連続投票については、システムが自動的に検知してその投票がキャンセルされます。実際に機能していることは確認しています。

[image: voting corrected]

[信用度ページで、「連続賛成/反対投票が取り消されました」 で信用度が変更されているのはなぜですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

> あなたのアカウントに不正投票が発生中であるか、つい最近発生した場合は、心配しないでください。気づいてから、心配するまで少なくとも 24 時間お待ちください。自動システムが検知して取り消されるはずです。この期間が過ぎても信用度が修正されない場合は、任意のページの下にある [お問い合わせ] フォームを使用してチームにお問い合わせください。

自動検知の対象となる閾値は不明ですが、悪用を避けるために公開されることはないように思われます。

恣意的な投票が疑われる場合は、[問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)をして調査してもらうことが可能なようです。

Comment: 問い合わせでもいいですが、まま遅いです。カスタムな通報をあげたら、モデレーターが弊職を呼ぶこともできますので、それも一つの方法です。